# Facebook App ID - Multiple Site URL's

Tags: facebook, app-id

I have a product consisting of hundreds of separate websites - each of which has a unique URL. Unfortunately it is not feasible for me to create a separate Facebook App ID for each website. Is it possible to configure one Facebook App ID that can be shared/used across all websites?

I know it's possible with subdomains but haven't had any luck finding much information about my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. The only way it so redirect to a login page that is the same for all.